# How can I get things back after git reset --hard

Tags: git

I miscalculate the commit sequence, and things gone.

Is there any other way to get things back?

Thanks.

Comment: use "git reflog" yo will see many lines like this: 1f5bd18 HEAD@{1}: commit: work finished      Then use "git reset --hard 1f5bd18" (see that 1f5bd18 string is the id of the commit that you want to revert to)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git reflog` and `git fsck` are your weapons of choice to rediscover the missing commits and branch them.